# bootstrap toggle and if statements

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, toggleswitch

I am trying to create 3 toggles using bootstrap and I added some if statements, some of them worked but the rest are not working

this is my complete code

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Form Helpers Basic Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<input id="toggle-email" checked type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></i> Email On" data-off="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i> Email OFF" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-width="150">


<input id="toggle-phone" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></i> Phone On" data-off="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i> Phone OFF" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-width="150">

<br>
<br>

<input id="toggle-both" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></i> Email & Phone On" data-off="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i> Email & Phone OFF" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-width="300">



<script>
 
 
 
 $(function() {
  
  
  $("#toggle-email").on("change", function () {
   if (this.checked) {
    $('#toggle-phone').bootstrapToggle('off');
    $('#toggle-both').bootstrapToggle('off');
   }
   else{
    $('#toggle-phone').bootstrapToggle('on');
    $('#toggle-both').bootstrapToggle('off');
   }
  })
  
  $("#toggle-phone").on("change", function () {
   if (this.checked) {
    $('#toggle-email').bootstrapToggle('off');
    $('#toggle-both').bootstrapToggle('off');
   }
   else{
    $('#toggle-email').bootstrapToggle('on');
    $('#toggle-both').bootstrapToggle('off');
   }
  })
  
  $("#toggle-both").on("change", function () {
   if (this.checked) {
    $('#toggle-email').bootstrapToggle('on');
    $('#toggle-phone').bootstrapToggle('on');
   }
   else{
    $('#toggle-email').bootstrapToggle('on');
    $('#toggle-phone').bootstrapToggle('off');
    
   }
  })
  
  
  
  
 });
 
 
</script>



<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

the if statements are clear and easy to understand my point

any suggestions?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was trying to run your snippet, I kept wondering why I was getting this weird error. After digging through the plugin's documentation, I came across this issue [#31](https://github.com/minhur/bootstrap-toggle/issues/31). Basically, the `change` event is being triggered when you call the `.bootstrapToggle()` method. But in your code, you have `change` event handlers that call `.bootstrapToggle()` -- so you are basically firing `change()` event recursively over and over -- which gives the undesired behavior.

Using [one of the commenters' solutions](https://github.com/minhur/bootstrap-toggle/issues/31#issuecomment-137263900), you could do:

```js
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle=toggle]', function() {
  var input = $(this).find('input')[0]; 
  switch (input.id) {
    case 'toggle-email':
      $('#toggle-phone').bootstrapToggle(!input.checked ? 'on' : 'off');
      $('#toggle-both').bootstrapToggle('off');
      break;
    case 'toggle-phone':
      $('#toggle-email').bootstrapToggle(!input.checked ? 'on' : 'off');
      $('#toggle-both').bootstrapToggle('off');
      break;
    case 'toggle-both':
      $('#toggle-email').bootstrapToggle('on');
      $('#toggle-phone').bootstrapToggle(input.checked ? 'on' : 'off');
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>



<input id="toggle-email" checked type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></i> Email On" data-off="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i> Email OFF" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-width="150">


<input id="toggle-phone" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></i> Phone On" data-off="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i> Phone OFF" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-width="150">

<input id="toggle-both" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></i> Email & Phone On" data-off="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i> Email & Phone OFF" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-width="300">
```

Basically, I am attaching a `click` event handler on the wrapper that gets created around the `input` element (hence why I use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)) and using it to make the changes.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working now! my knowledge about javascript and jquery is very low but I am working on python flask and wanted to add this feature, thanks again